# Send asynchronous emails in Magento 1.6

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

In Magento how to send emails (order, new user etc) asynchronously?

In my production instance calls like `$mailer->send();` takes around 40 to 60 seconds.

Comment: Magento 1.9.1. provide such feature as put email sending in queue

Comment: Unfortunately, we can not upgrade to 1.9.1. Is there any option to pull only the email queue related modules to 1.6 from 1.9.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Redis for queuing mechanism, where in mail details would be pushed to Redis list based queue (using `lpush` command) and poped at the worker (using `brpop` command)